# fluent nhibernate wont work with the new nhibernate 3.1ga?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

when i ran the program, it threw an io exception that cant find dll "NHibernate, Version=3.0.0.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4" or something like it. 
what i've done is just replace the nhibernate 3.0ga dll with the 3.1ga.
so the fluent nhibernate really cant work with nhibernate 3.1? how should i make them work together?
 thanks for any help offered.

Answer (score 3):

You can put [assembly redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in configuration file

Answer (score 2):

Build Fluent NH from the sources, or wait until a version targetting NH 3.1 is released.